# How can I extract the domain from an url or email with a sql select statement?

Tags: sql, email, select, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I want is to extract only the domain, without the top domain.

I have two fields, email and website. With two different sql SELECT statements, one for each of the fields, I want to create two new fields, EmailDomain and WebsiteDomain.

Examples of fields in website:

- https://www.example.com/index.html
- test.domain.com
- domain.com
- [www.domain.co.uk](http://www.domain.co.uk)
- domain.se
- etc.

Examples of values in email:

- name@domain.stormgeo.com
- name@domain.com
- name@test.domain.com
- name@domain.co.uk
- etc.

In all the examples above, I want the result to be "domain" (or "example") only.

I have tested and come up with some statements that almost makes the job, but they don't fix all the examples and they still have the top domain.

What I have so far is:

`` SELECT Account.website, REGEXP_REPLACE (Account.website, '(http[s]?://)?(www\\.)?(.*?)((/|:)(.)*|$)', '\\3') AS `WebsiteDomain` FROM Account ``

and

`` SELECT Leads.email, REGEXP_REPLACE (Leads.email, '^.*@([^\\.]+)\\.\\w+','\\1') AS `EmailDomain` FROM  Leads ``

Comment: What would be the desired output for those 2 sets of sample data? Please also tag you database and version

Comment: In all the examples above, I want the result to be "domain" (or "example") only. So, the domain without top-domain or anything else.

The database is Google BigQuery with Standard SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select website, regexp_replace(net.reg_domain(website), '.' || net.public_suffix(website) || '$', '') 
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

You should be able to apply same to email field